# paste the data from web page to textarea in mobile app using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to paste the content from web browser to the text area in my phonegap app.my app has a textarea ,while typing into textarea i should give an option to paste the content from web page.when i browse something in mobile,if i select any data there is a option to copy but data is copied to clipboard.i want to paste that selected data directly into textarea?

please help me in this

Comment: let me see if i understood correctly your question... you want to be able to paste text you copied from the browser, into your phonegap application form input? it doesn't work natively? like by default?

Comment: This comment will not be helpfull now, but phonegap or apache cordova is poorly documented and generally hard work. Have a go with appcelerator.. by far the best abstraction layer IMO